# Java Script Functions Don't work and How do i add my javascript file to html and get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have my javascript file and code done, called script.js and I've added it to my HTML file. I'm very new to this and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. the functions don't seem to work either. I am very lost and would just like yo figure it out. thank you.

this is my javascript file called (script.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//When add database, will pull total from database
var total = 30;
var totalTax = total * 0.8;
var totalShip = total * 0.3;
var totalAll = total + totalTax + totalShip;
document.getElementById("totalShop").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementById("totalTax").innerHTML = totalTax;
document.getElementById("shipping").innerHTML = totalShip;
document.getElementById("totalDue").innerHTML = totalAll;
});

function applyActiveCss(id) {

for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    if (document.links[i].id == id) {
        document.links[i].className = 'active';

    }

    else {

        document.links[i].className = 'links';
    }
  }
}

function validateCheckout() {

if (document.checkoutForm.cardNumber.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide card number");
    document.checkoutForm.cardNumber.focus();
    return false;
}

if (document.checkoutForm.month.value == "" || isNaN(document.checkoutForm.month.value) ||
   document.checkoutForm.month.value.length != 2) {
    alert("Please provide your month");
    document.checkoutForm.month.focus();
    return false;
}

if (document.checkoutForm.year.value == "" || isNaN(document.checkoutForm.year.value) ||
   document.checkoutForm.year.value.length != 4) {
    alert("Please provide your month");
    document.checkoutForm.year.focus();
    return false;
  }
 return (true);
}

function validateUserInfo() {

if (document.userInfo.fullname.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide full name");
    document.checkoutForm.cardNumber.focus();
    return false;
}

if (document.userInfo.email.value == "") {
    alert("Please provide your Email!");
    document.userInfo.email.focus();
    return false;
}

var emailID = document.userInfo.email.value;
var atpos = emailID.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = emailID.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos < 1 || (dotpos - atpos < 2)) {
    alert("Please enter correct email ID")
    document.userInfo.email.focus();
    return false;
}

if (document.userInfo.zipcode.value == "" || 
 isNaN(document.userInfo.zipcode.value) ||
   document.userInfo.zipcode.value.length != 5) {

    alert("Please provide a zip in the format 12345");
    document.userInfo.zipcode.focus();
    return false;
}
var phoneID = document.userInfo.phone.value;
var dashpos1 = phoneID.indexOf("-");
var dashpos2 = phoneID.lastIndexOf("-");

for (var i = 3; i < 7; i++) {
    phoneID[i] = phoneID[i + 1];
}

for (var j = 6; j < 8; j++) {
    phoneID[j] = phoneID[j + 2];
}

if (document.userInfo.phone.value == "" || 
 document.userInfo.phone.value.length != 12
    || dashpos1 != 3 || dashpos2 != 7 || isNaN(phoneID)) {
    alert("Please provide a phone number in the format 123-456-7890");
    document.userInfo.phone.focus();
    return false;
  }
 return (true);
}
```

and this is part of my HTML file called (userinfo.html)

```
¿<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Personal Information</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css">  
</head>

<body>

<script src="script.js"> </script>

<h1>User Information</h1>
<p>Please fill out the following information.</p>
<!--<form class="" action="submit.php" method="post">-->
<form action=".shipinfo.html" name="userInfo" onsubmit="return (validateUserInfo());">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Full Name: <br>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="fullname" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Phone Number: <br>
                    <input type="number" minlength = "12" maxlength="12" name="phone"  
                           placeholder="123-456-7890">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Address Line 1: <br>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="add1" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Address Line 2: <br>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="add2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    City: <br>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="100" name="city" required>
                </td>
```

Comment: you should have to include `Jquery` file just before your `script.js`

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the following jquery script in your file (so it does not read the document ready part and you do not see the 'document loaded' in your console.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Another error you are getting in the console is 'Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null' for this:

```
  document.getElementById("totalShip").innerHTML = total;
```

This happens when the element, in this case 'totalship', is not accessible or available in your webpage and as such its property cannot be read. Since you are accessing an id, can you provide your css file here?
In addition, where is the access to your database through these files (.userInfo, .checkoutForm etc.) are not accessible via your files as of now.